# TypeError: argument of type 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' is not iterable

Tags: python, spacy

I need to check if the subject of the sentence exist in a list, but I have some problems with this error and I don't understand how can I fix it

```
def __init__(self, user_input):
    personal_words = ["I", "ME", "US"]
    er = ["YOU"]
    pos = pop(user_input)
    for token in pos:
        if token.dep == nsubj:
            subject = token
            print(subject)
            if any(item in subject for item in personal_words):
                personal()
            elif any(item in subject for item in er):
                era()
            else:
                n_personal()
```

> TypeError: argument of type 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug – the `Token` object is a container object for the data of a single token, not an iterable sequence. In your code, you're checking `item in subject`, which expects `subject` (the token) to be a sequence. If you want to check whether the token text matches a string, you actually want to be checking `token.text == string`.

Answer (score 0):

As it should be iterable I supposed the problem is related to some bug in the internals possibly version specific (by the way, please next time share a bit more about your environment i.e. what version of of the different frameworks you are using)
After a search I have found this one which seems to be related

[TypeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object is not iterable](https://github.com/cedias/Hierarchical-Sentiment/issues/3)

Just copy-pasting the proposed solutions

```
@larry0123du I solved this by installing Spacy==1.9 (I was using Spacy==2.0 before)
```

```
if word is "spacy.tokens.token.Token",you can chage it to "word.text" in Spacy==2.018 @larry0123du @ @brandenchan
```

Comment: I found this too but dosen't work. My output is a string, I tried to convert to a list and told me this TypeError: Argument 'other' has incorrect type (expected spacy.tokens.token.Token, got str) I used this subject = []
                subject.append(token)